# How to populate and display all images dynamically through a placeholder using a for loop in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net C# webforms project. I have to debug an issue where once in a while I get "A generic error occurred in GDI+" error. This may be due to too many people accessing the site at the same time. In order to mimic it, I want to create a for loop to create thousands of images and display it through the placeholder. The problem is that, the loop runs and only the last image shows up. I would like to see each and every image created in the loop to be displayed on the page. The following is the code:

```
        protected void btnGenerateBarCode_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgBarCode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
        var codabar = new ZXing.BarcodeWriter();
        codabar.Options = options;
        codabar.Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_128;

        for (int i = 1000; i < 2000; i++)
            {
                using (Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(codabar.Write(i.ToString())))
                {
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                        byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();

                        Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
                        imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
                    }
        //the placeholder control on the page
                    plBarCode.Controls.Add(imgBarCode);
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: You're adding the same control over an over again - either get plBarCode.Controls.Add() out of your For/Next loop, or put your new Image() inside it. If you want to use different controls, you'll need to position them using incrementing X/Y points. If you want to cycle all through one control, you'll need to add a Load() and a delay otherwise the UI thread won't have time to update between images and you'll only see the end frame (like an animation)

Answer (score 0):

```
The problem is that, the loop runs and only the last image shows up.
```

This is because you actually create only one control outside of your loop. Add the image creation inside the loop as:

```
protected void btnGenerateBarCode_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var codabar = new ZXing.BarcodeWriter();
    codabar.Options = options;
    codabar.Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_128;

    for (int i = 1000; i < 2000; i++)
        {
            using (Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(codabar.Write(i.ToString())))
            {
                //  Here create the image control
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgBarCode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                    byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();

                    Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
                    imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
                }
                //the placeholder control on the page
                plBarCode.Controls.Add(imgBarCode);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi Aristos, this code creates multiple controls and display the barcode. Is there anyway a single control is used and the image is replaced with new one and the loop runs? Thanks

Comment: @Ocean Direct render it to a string, then just add the string on a literal